# How to pass argument to function - dealing with reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have some problems with C++.
I build application using GAlib library (it's a C++ Library of Genetic Algorithm Components - http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/).

In one of examples (full code of example: http://lancet.mit.edu/galib-2.4/examples/ex6.C) author create function that initializes tree:

```
void TreeInitializer(GAGenome & c)
{
  GATreeGenome<int> &child=(GATreeGenome<int> &)c;

// destroy any pre-existing tree
  child.root();
  child.destroy();

// Create a new tree with depth of 'depth' and each eldest node containing
// 'n' children (the other siblings have none).
  int depth=2, n=2, count=0;
  child.insert(count++,GATreeBASE::ROOT);

  for(int i=0; i<depth; i++){
    child.eldest();
    child.insert(count++);
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
      child.insert(count++,GATreeBASE::AFTER);
  }
}
```

He invoke function in that way:

```
genome.initializer(TreeInitializer);
```

and He don't pass an argument. When I trying pass argument to that function by changing declaration for example:

```
void TreeInitializer(GAGenome &, int deph);
```

Compiler shows me errors. I don't know how to invoke this function properly. I know it's related to reference but passing (or not passing) argument in that way is new to me.

How to pass more arguments to that function?

Comment: He is passing a pointer to the function. `genome.initializer` takes the pointer and calls the function as many times as it needs to. If you want the function to accept more arguments, you need to first change the type (signature) of the expected function (something like `void (*f)(GAGenome&, int)`), and then every time the `initializer` calls `f`, pass an extra argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `genome.initializer(TreeInitializer);` does not call `TreeInitializer` - instead, it passes the pointer to that function to `genome.initializer`, so it can call it with whatever arguments it needs/multiple times. If you want `TreeInitializer` to accept more arguments, you need to modify the `initializer` to accept a different type of function. It is probably defined as

```
void initializer(void (*f)(GAGenome&))
{
    // ...
    f(genome);
    // ...
}
```

You need to change the argument type to `void (*f)(GAGenome&, int)` and change the lines that call `f`.

On the other hand, if you can't modify the initializer function but want to be able to specify the depth, then the best you can do is make a global variable that you set to whatever depth you need and have `TreeInitializer` use that variable. It isn't a clean solution if you think global variables are evil, but it's your only choice if the `initializer` doesn't let you supply any "context".

Comment: I have more variables to pass so I didn't want use global variables but know I think is the quickest way. I found in library code this: <code>typedef void (*Initializer)(GAGenome &);</code> and further <code> void initialize(){_evaluated=gaFalse; _neval=0; 
(*init)(*this);} 
Initializer initializer() const {return init;} 
Initializer initializer(Initializer op){return (init=op);} </code>

So it's little difrent between this and your example. What should I change?

Comment: If you really want to modify the library code to allow you to pass an extra argument (up to you to figure out if it makes much sense), then you need to add a second argument to the typedef (`typedef void (Initializer)(GAGenome&,int)`), then add an int member to the class, make a way to set it (probably from the `initializer` function), and have `initialize()` call `(*init)(*this, value)`, where `value` is the member variable you added.

Answer (score -1):

What you what to do in

```
GATreeGenome<int> &child=(GATreeGenome<int> &)c;
```

is a casting from a GAGenome to GATreeGenome . If you haven't a casting operator for this case, it won't work...

Comment: The cast __will__ work even if a conversion operator is not provided. Your answer does not address the actual question. -1.

Comment: Why? GATreeGenome<int> and GaGenome are two different classes.

Comment: Casting to an unrelated type will result undefined behavior but the cast will __still__ be performed. If `GATreeGenome<int>` derives `GaGenome` a `static_cast` is used otherwise `reinterpret_cast` will be used. `class Foo {};
class Bar {};

const Bar& ptr = (Bar&)Foo(); // cast still happens.`

Comment: Yes, it is so if we cast pointers to another pointer of a different type. But here aren't pointers. Try to compile this: class A {
 int x;
 short z;
};

class B {
 int y;
 char* s;
};

int main() {
 A a;
 B b=a;
} // g++ gives error "t.cc:13:6: error: conversion from 'A' to non-scalar type 'B' requested"